# Boundedness from below and density of range

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and $T: H \to H$ linear and bounded operator. Suppose
$$ \langle Tx, x \rangle \ge \|x\|^2 \quad \quad \text{ for all } x \in H $$

I can prove this implies injectivity of $T$ and closeness of its range. Is it true that $T$ is surjective? In other words, can I prove its range is also dense?

Comment: Do you assume that $H$ is separable?

Comment: No I don't. In this case would it be surjective?

Comment: No actually I'm not sure.

Comment: For your definition of bounded below, do you mean $\langle Tx, Tx \rangle \geq \lvert x \rvert^2$?

Comment: @bitesizebo No, is the inequality I wrote

Comment: @Bremen000 I finally got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your claim will follow from the following Lemma

> Let $H$ be an Hilbert space, $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a continuous map. Then, if $T^\star$ is injective with closed range then $T$ is surjective

See proof here [A proof that $T^*$ injective with closed range implies $T$ is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665235/a-proof-that-t-injective-with-closed-range-implies-t-is-surjective) .

You have $\left<x,T^\star x\right> \geq \|x\|^2$ and so your conclusions on $T$ are also true for $T^\star$ (same proof). Therefore, $T^\star$ is injective and has a closed range. Thus, by the lemma $T$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought the following thing while you were writing: I prove $T(H)^{\perp} = \{ 0 \}$, indeed if $y \in T(H)^{\perp}$ we have $(y,Tx)=0$ for every $x \in H$, in particular $0=(y,Ty) \ge \|y\|^2$ and this implies the claim.

Comment: @Bremen000 wow that's so much simpler. I guess this is the direct way without going through $T^\star$.