# A surjective linear operator - Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space.

Such that we have a linear operator $T$
$$T: H\rightarrow H'$$
such that there exists $C>0$, $\langle Tx,x\rangle_{H,H'}\geq C \|x\|_{H}^2$.

Obviously, $T$ is injective, but why is $T$ surjective ?

Comment: Perhaps you can use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/665235/27978 ?

Comment: How is $\langle Tx, x \rangle$ defined if $x \in H$ and $Tx \in H'$?

Comment: Or maybe you mean $H'$ is dual to $H$, but since $H$ is self-dual etc. etc. etc . . .

Comment: I missed the $H,H'$ confusion.

Comment: $H'$ is the topologic dual of $H$, and for the duality product $<.>$ is defined as follows: $<Tx,x>=(Tx)(x)$ since $Tx \in H'$